# How to fix correlator memory allocation error in GNSS SDRLIB while post processing?

Tags: rtl-sdr, gnss

[image: GNSS SDRLIB plots]

I am using GNSS SDRLIB for postprocessing a RTL SDR signal sample and as you can see I was able to get the acquisition of the satellites, however I'm not getting any position fixes (the obs file is empty). I believe this is due to this correlator memory allocation error.

I don't have a different signal sample so I do not know if it's the problem with the file. I have tried this on multiple PCs and was getting the same result.

Please help me fix this error. This file was downloaded from [sdr ion](https://sdr.ion.org/api-sample-data.html), if you have a different file that works, please share it if you can.

Comment: Hi! Welcome here! Sadly, your question is neither about amateur radio nor about the technology / theory of radio in general, and therefore off-topic.